# post request is not working to upload files to S3 pre-signed URL but put works using angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, post, amazon-s3, httpclient, pre-signed-url

I want to upload files to S3 pre-signed URL that I have produced using my back end application. For the front end, I am using angular HttpClient v8.2.9
when I use put request it is working in which the code looks like this.

```
const formData = new FormData();
           formData.append('file', file, file.name);
           this.http.put(preSignedUrl, formData, {
             responseType: 'text'
           }).subscribe(respond => {
                 console.log('__________OK_________');
                 console.log(respond);
               },
               error => {
                 console.log('__________ERROR_________');
                 console.log(error);
               });
```

but when I use post request I always get an error saying that

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

and the cod for the post request would be like this.

```
const formData = new FormData();
           formData.append('file', file, file.name);
           this.http.post(preSignedUrl, formData, {
             responseType: 'text'
           }).subscribe(respond => {
                 console.log('__________OK_________');
                 console.log(respond);
               },
               error => {
                 console.log('__________ERROR_________');
                 console.log(error);
               });
         });
```

since the produced pre-signed URL could also be for my own microservice which has ability to receive files through post request, I can not use amazon libraries to upload files in the front-end and has to be something general. The example of post request above is working with my microservice which I am happy with and I want to make the S3 work with the post as well. So I don't have to change my request based on where I am uploading to.

Here is the code for my java back-end that I produce the pre-signed URL for S3

```
AmazonS3 s3client = makeClient();
                Date expirationTime = calculateExpirationTime();
                GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
                        new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, fullPath, HttpMethod.PUT);
                                    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expirationTime);

                return s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest).toString();
```

if I change the back end code for HttpMethod to POST I also get the same error and also put request in the front end will not work.

Answer (score 0):

again I think I found what issue is. I just post it here if someone else has this issue.
If we look at the documentation for the s3 SDK. To generate a pre-signed URL we can not use POST.

> ```
>  * @param method
>  *            The HTTP method (GET, PUT, DELETE, HEAD) to be used in the
>  *            request when the pre-signed URL is used.
> ```

So in my situation PUT is the best fit.

I also found the link bellow 
https://www.intelliware.com/submitting-a-multipart-request-multipartform-data-using-put-and-spring-boot/

where it says

spring boot only expects a multipart/form-data as part of a POST request

So what I need to do is that I need to override the spring method to accept put a request for multipart upload.